# If three cards are selected at random without replacement. What is the probability that all three are Kings?

Tags: probability

This a two part question:

$1$: If three cards are selected at random without replacement. What is the probability that all three are Kings? In a deck of $52$ cards.

$2$: Can you please explain to me in lay man terms what is the difference between with and without replacement.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Without Replacement:** You shuffle the deck thoroughly, take out **three** cards. For this particular problem, the question is "What is the probability these cards are all Kings."

**With Replacement:** Shuffle the deck, pick out **one** card, record what you got. Then put it **back in the deck**, shuffle, pick out one card, record what you got. Then put it back in the deck, pick out one card, record what you got. One might then ask for the probability that all three recorded cards were Kings. In the with replacement situation, it is possible, for example, to get the $\spadesuit$ King, or the $\diamondsuit$ Jack more than once.

For solving the "without replacement" problem, here are a couple of ways. There are $\binom{52}{3}$ equally likely ways to choose $3$ cards. There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ Kings. So our probability is $\binom{4}{3}/\binom{52}{3}$.

Or else imagine taking out the cards one at a time. The probability the first card taken out was a King is $\frac{4}{52}$.  **Given** that the first card taken out was a King, the probability the second one was  is $\frac{3}{51}$, since there are $51$ cards left of which $3$ are Kings. So the probability the first two cards were Kings is $\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{3}{51}$. **Given that the first two were Kings, the probability the third is is $\frac{2}{50}$. So the desired probability is $\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{3}{51}\cdot \frac{2}{50}$.

**Remark:** We could solve the same three Kings problem under the "with replacement" condition. (You were not asked to do that,) The second approach we took above yields the answer $\left(\frac{4}{52}\right)^3$. Since we are replacing the card each time and shuffling, the probability of what the "next" card is is not changed by the knowledge that the first card was a King.

Comment: Nicolas: 4/52+3/51+2/50 does that seem okay?

Comment: Well, no. I have added two solutions to the numerical problem.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas: So the only mistake I did was I added them instead of multiplying the fractions?

Comment: Yes, if you replace addition by multiplication, the answer becomes right. Using addition involves a wrong analysis of the problem.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas  The answer is 1.81*10^-4 but I get 1/5525

Comment: If you find the reciprocal of $5525$ in your calculator, you will discover that your answers are in agreement.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas you mean flip the fraction upside down? 5525/1?

Comment: You say you got the answer $\frac{1}{5525}$. Use your calculator to find what that is approximately as a decimal. Depending on whether your calculator is set to scientific notation or not, you will get something like $1.81\times 10^{-4}$ or $0.000181$.

Comment: thank you I got 0.000181 but I was confused when it wasn't in scientific form

Comment: This post helped me to see how one should reason about such questions. Another example similar to this im trying to solve, is: probability of having 3 kings after 8 simultaneous cards are taken from a deck of 52? (Without replacement), my answer is: binomial(4,3)/binomial(52,8). Is that ok? Am i missing something?

Comment: @user929304:  There is a missing term. There are $\binom{52}{8}$ equally likely ways to choose $8$ cards. That's the denominator, you got it right. Now let us count the number of **favourables**. There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ kings. For **each** of these ways, there are $\binom{48}{5}$ ways to choose the $5$ non-kings, for a total of $\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{5}$.

Comment: For more information about the above type of problem, please see *hypergeometric distribution*, say on Wikipedia or elsewhere.

Comment: You are welcome. The question above did not illustrate the $\binom{48}{5}$ part, because we were only picking $3$ cards.

Comment: @user929304: Nothing really special comes to mind at the right level. Maybe Sheldon Ross, title contains the words Probability Models.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What's the probability that the first card would be a King? The second? And the third?

With replacement means that after you draw the card you put it back into the deck, then re-draw the next one completely random.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, dear MethodManX, while computing probabilities, addition refers to "or", multiplication - to "and". Here you have "and": the first card is a King AND the second is a King AND the fird is a King, so it's rather $\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{3}{52}\cdot\frac{2}{52}$.

Answer (score 0):

4/52*3/51*2/50 =(24/13260)or(1/5525)same as (0.0018)remember when there's an "or" put
a cross over the letter "O" & remember to add rather than mutliply.When there's a plus sign
between remember to multiply.